# What are the necessary conditions for the Stolz-Cesàro theorem?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What are the necessary conditions for Stolz-Cesàro theorem?

Let there be two sequences: $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$. Is it possible to use this theorem if $(y_n)$ converges to zero?

Answer (score 0):

You have to have that $y_n$  is strictly monotone and divergent sequence
[Stolz-Cesaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem)